# IDE throwing strange error with System.Exit(#)

Tags: xml, debugging

I've been trying to debug this file for a couple days, and I keep on getting caught up on one point. The System.Exit(9999) causes some error. When I comment it out, it builds and executes fine. Without it commented out I get

There is a problem with the Eagle. It throws the following error:

```
/**Users/Capocolla/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 15** <<--this is the odd error.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is the output I'm after.

There is a problem with the Eagle!

- `Java Result: 9999`

  ```
  public class EagleLandingException extends Exception
          {

  public EagleLandingException(String msg)

  {
   super(msg);
    }
      }
  public class ThrowEagleExceptionTest {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      try {
          EagleLanding();
      }
      catch(EagleLandingException badEagle)
      {
          System.out.printf("%s\n", badEagle.getMessage());
          System.exit(9999);
      }
  }

  private static void EagleLanding() throws EagleLandingException
  {
      throw new EagleLandingException("There is a problem with the Eagle!");
  }
  ```

  }